# variable scope in golang

Tags: arrays, go, scope

I am new in Go language and want to learn basic fundamental  here below I paste example. the problem in this example is I cannot access number variable inside for loop. it shows this error

> " number declared and not use "

. Please help me :(

```
package main
import(
    "fmt"
)

func main() {    
    samlestNumber()
}

func samlestNumber()  {
    x := []int{
        48,96,86,68,
        57,82,63,70,
        37,34,83,27,
        19,97, 9,17,
    }

    //x = append(x,6,7)
    var number int = x[0]
    for _,element := range x {

        if element < x[0] {
            number = element
        }    
        fmt.Println(" :::: ",element)    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are only declaring and assigning values to `number`. You are never actually using it anywhere (i.e. referring to the value it holds in any way). In you code, you can safely remove `number` declaration and `number = x[0]` and it won't change the program behavior.

The correct implementation however would return the smallest number from the function:

```
package main
import(
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    n := samlestNumber()
    fmt.Println("Smallest Number =", n)
}

func samlestNumber() int { // add a return type
    x := []int{
        48,96,86,68,
        57,82,63,70,
        37,34,83,27,
        19,97, 9,17,
    }

    //x = append(x,6,7)
    var number int = x[0]
    for _,element := range x {

        // always compare to smallest number. Even if you don't return
        // number anymore, you are still accessing the value held by
        // the number variable. So even making this change alone will
        // make the compiler error go away 
        if element < number {
            number = element
        }

        fmt.Println(" :::: ",element)
    }
    return number // return number
}
```